# How to use configuration environment files with ctm.yaml in control-m

Tags: control-m

I want to send to different email recipients when my job is ok for distinct environments (test, prod) pro example. Currently i use a folder env_files/* with prod_env.conf, test_env.conf, so inside these file are variables such export VAULT_TYPE=SOMETYPE etc.. I added to my conf files: export EMAIL_ENV=someemail@somemail.com and tried to use that variable into my ctm.yaml.

That is, I tried to call the variable in my ctm.yaml using distinct ways such %%GETENV EMAIL_ENV, ${EMAIL_ENV} or %%EMAIL_ENV, for example:

mailToTeam:
Type: Action:Mail
Subject: Job %%JOBNAME Success
Message: Job %%JOBNAME success in ${RUNTIME_ENV}, ${EMAIL_ENV}
To: ${EMAIL_ENV}

But neither of variation to call the variable EMAIL_ENV to use the placeholder in my ctm.yaml works. In overall, how can i use the variables defined in my conf files into my ctm.yaml?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of error are you getting? If you see "CTMERR" then that means the error is at the Control-M level and the variable is not being resolved there.

With this kind of requirement (i.e. basic static variables) I'd be tempted to use the LIBMEMSYM facility and have different LIBMEMSYM files defined for Prod, Test, etc.

The LIBMEMSYM is a text file that you define in the job or at Smart Folder level. The text file needs to be readable by the Control-M jobs and is usually kept on the Control-M Server itself.

E.g. in your Test job, in the Variables, define LIBMEMSYM with /cmserver/variables/libmemsym/test.txt and the file contents as -

```
%%EMAIL_ALERT=test_group@abc.com
%%SERVER=TEST1_SRV
%%DB=DB_TST54
```

and /cmserver/variables/libmemsym/prod.txt as -

```
%%EMAIL_ALERT=prod_group@abc.com
%%SERVER=PR1_SRV
%%DB=DB_PRD81
```

The only difference between the 2 jobs (or smart folders) is the LIBMEMSYM definition.